# VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Why do I get this error for the following formula?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(Q8:Q1000&" "&"You",{A8:A1000&" "&B8:B1000,C8:C1000},3,false))
```

I have tried this as well

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(Q8:Q&" "&"You",{A8:A&" "&B8:B,C8:C},3,false))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{A8:A1000&" "&B8:B1000, C8:C1000}` is wide only two columns, therefore use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(Q8:Q&" "&"You", {A8:A&" "&B8:B, C8:C}, 2, 0)))
```